# Power BI average rating per product

Tags: average, powerbi, summarization

I have a `Ratings` table with some product ratings:

```
productKey   rating
product-1    4
product-1    5
product-2    3
```

I want to calculate the average rating per product:

- **Incorrect average (default)**: `(4+5+3)/3 = 12/3 = 4`
- **Average per product** : `( (4+5)/2 + 3 ) / 2 = (4.5 + 3) / 2 = 3.75`

I managed to do this with an intermediate table

1) Create table which averages ratings per product:

```
RatingsPerProd = SUMMARIZE(Ratings,Ratings[productKey],"averageRating",AVERAGE(Ratings[rating]))
```

which creates the following table:

```
productKey   averageRating
product-1    4.5
product-2    3
```

2) Then I simply do an `AVERAGE` of `averageRating`

However I'd like to do this with 1 single measure on the original `Ratings` table, but whatever I try to do with the `SUMMARIZE` formula I get the following error:

> The expression refers to multiple columns... cannot be converted to a
>   scalar value

**How can I achieve average per product in 1 single measure on the original Ratings table?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following formula:

```
AveragePerProduct =
AVERAGEX (
    VALUES ( Ratings[productKey] ),
    CALCULATE ( AVERAGE ( Ratings[rating] ) )
)
```

Result:

[image: Power BI]